# Given that "genetic drift" can happen, why is searching for an adaptive explanation for traits considered an important scientific question?

Tags: evolution, natural-selection

I saw today on [Wikenigma](https://wikenigma.org.uk/content/life_sciences/zoology/zebra_stripes) (a wiki for open questions in science) that there are many competing explanations for why zebra stripes are evolutionarily adaptive, and there is no consensus on which one(s) are correct.

The discussion there suggests that **scientists are eager to explain the specific adaptive advantage conferred by zebra stripes**—for example, to find evidence showing that zebra stripes help the animals regulate their body temperature.

However, we know that there is a phenomenon called [genetic drift](https://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolution-101/mechanisms-the-processes-of-evolution/genetic-drift/) by which certain genes come to dominate a population "just because": These genes are *neutral* with respect to evolutionary fitness, but happen to secure a majority early on in the lineage, and this majority grows over time:

> Genetic drift is one of the basic mechanisms of evolution.
>
> In each generation, some individuals may, just by chance, leave behind a few more descendants (and genes, of course!) than other individuals. The genes and other genetic elements of the next generation will be those of the “lucky” individuals, not necessarily the healthier or “better” individuals. That, in a nutshell, is genetic drift. It happens to ALL populations — there’s no avoiding the vagaries of chance.
>
> …
>
> Genetic drift affects the genetic makeup of the population, but unlike natural selection, through an entirely random process. So although genetic drift is a mechanism of evolution, it doesn’t work to produce adaptations.

Let's fix the meaning of *adaptations* here:

> An adaptation is a feature that arose and was favored by natural selection for its current function. Adaptations help an organism survive and/or reproduce in its current environment.

[(source)](https://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolution-101/mechanisms-the-processes-of-evolution/adaptation/)

My question is, **given that "genetic drift" can happen, why is searching for an adaptive explanation for traits considered an important scientific question?**

### Non-questions

- **Zebra stripes are a motivating example for this post, but not the central theme.** If you believe that zebra stripes *do* confer a specific adaptive advantage, then please substitute "zebra stripes" with a trait whose adaptive advantage you cannot identify.

Comment: I'm not sure that I see the justification for point 3, as that's the only place that you've specified that the father has some fitness advantage. Zebra stripes have a known adaptive advantage - did you look them up, what did you find? If something is preferentially selected for, then it is by definition a selective advantage, it doesn't make any difference if it's due to the feature being attractive or a good survival trait - see peacock tails as example of female selectivity of non-advantageous trait. Can you clarify?

Comment: Point 3 is mentioned in the preceding paragraph. Your first question is addressed by my first "non-question." Your second question feels like a semantic issue: you say "selective" advantage but I chose the word "adaptive" on purpose, because the search for an explanation for zebra stripes seems deliberately targeted toward adaptive explanations and nobody seems content to take "the stripes are attractive" as an answer—and again, the zebra stripes are just an example, and you can substitute peacock tails if you think zebra stripes have an adaptive advantage.

Comment: “Can natural selection reward traits…?” Please consider carefully the meaning of the words “selection”, “reward” and “traits”, and you will see that your title is scientifically and linguistically meaningless. Traits may be selected, and one might say that evolution involves the selection of certain traits. That is the only relation between the two. “Reward” is not a feature of evolution in any sense.

Comment: “ Now suppose that a strong, adaptively fit male of this species happens to be born with a heritable sexual preference for trait A.” 1. That favors reproduction, which means selection. You can’t make it neutral just by placing a label on it. 2. How do you think traits evolve? A male just happens to be born with an interest in pattern “s”? Why would that happen in one jump? Is preferring a metal vs. a wooden frame a trait that is heritable? Your words… don’t seem to particularly comprehensible, and they certainly don’t mean what you seem to believe they do.

Comment: for neutral traits look up something called "genetic drift".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unclear (this includes your explanation for why you think the linked page doesn't answer whatever you are trying to ask) and under researched. In particular, this appears to be based on an inadequate understanding of the basics of evolutionary theory — I encourage you to spend time reading and thinking about the material in [this useful introduction to evolutionary theory from UC Berkeley](https://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_01).

Comment: I'm frustrated that many of the responses here seem to boil down to pointing out that I have used words in a different sense than evolutionary biologists do. I gave a clear example of what I mean by an "adaptively neutral" trait; while I understand that my example is technically "adaptively positive" in the sense that it favors reproduction, it is obviously qualitatively different from traits such as opposable thumbs that confer a specific biological advantage, and this distinction is at the heart of my question.

Comment: @anongoodnurse, I agree that "traits that favor selection" includes "traits that favor reproduction"—that's my point! But if you read the debate about zebra stripes, biologists aren't content with a circular explanation like "zebra stripes favor reproduction"—they are looking for a specific advantage such as "the stripes help them regulate their body temperature." My question is, why do biologists require such a specific explanation, if examples like mine are possible?

Comment: `A male just happens to be born with an interest in pattern “s”? Why would that happen in one jump?` The possibility of this happening follows directly from the following two premises: 1. Sexual preferences are influenced by genetics. 2. There are random variations in genes. Which of these premises is wrong?

Comment: At any rate, the concept of "genetic drift" mentioned by @John seems to best capture what I am asking about here. Let me reword my question to use this term in hopes of reducing confusion.

Comment: you are still going to have the issue with this being a very opinion based question. but as a side note something like visual patterning is unlikely to be neutral since vison is how predators and mates notice and identify you.

Comment: Sure, and I 3iterate: `Zebra stripes are a motivating example for this post, but not the central theme. If you believe that zebra stripes do confer a specific adaptive advantage, then please substitute "zebra stripes" with a trait whose adaptive advantage you cannot identify.`

Comment: @Max That's not really fair and seems to be a goalpost move. You posit that people search for adaptive explanations for things that need not be adaptive. Your evidence is so far one example; if that example isn't valid, why should we take your premise as true?

Comment: I don't know if the premise is true—one possible answer to my question is, "The debate about zebra stripes is unusual. In general, biologists assume that *most* traits arise from evolutionary drift." Is this your answer? I am asking because I don't know, not because I am trying to checkmate biologists. If I had a comprehensive knowledge of biology, then I would have chosen a better example, but then I wouldn't have needed to ask in the first place.

Comment: Ok, I will take on face value that you’re not trying to checkmate biologists. In that case, instead of arguing in comments, why not learn from them? You’re not going to get knowledge from arguing illogical arguments. Genetics doesn’t work the way you want it to work. A mutation is a point in a gene. It’s not likely to result in a completely new behavior. There are exceptions, but they are few and far between, and exceedingly difficult to prove. Lactase persistence is one, and it spread rapidly because of survival advantage. In fact, there are several SNP mutations that have similar results. …

Comment: …and we know this because of a lot of time, money, and research in different lactase persistent populations. What would prompt research into your scenario? I suspect nothing would, because it’s not a workable hypothesis.

Comment: With all due respect, I resent being accused of "arguing" when I have made every effort to understand the comments here, ask follow-up questions, and use your feedback to improve my post. From these two comments, it seems to me that your view is that "most traits, such as zebra stripes, have a specific adaptive advantage and aren't merely due to genetic drift." Is this an accurate summary? If so, please provide it as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: [This article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6662300/) may be an interesting read for you. You can also check out the Wikipedia pages on [adaptionism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptationism) and [constructive neutral evolution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_neutral_evolution).

Answer (score 5):

The very shortest answer, and in my opinion most ideologically neutral, is that [neutral evolution ("genetic drift") is the null hypothesis of evolution](https://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/neutral-theory-the-null-hypothesis-of-molecular-839/#:%7E:text=This%20process%20is%20called%20genetic,and%20the%20loss%20of%20others.).

The burden of proof is always on the person claiming adaptation. If you can't provide sufficient evidence for adaptation, the default is to assume neutrality.

Comment: This is a very surprising answer, if true, given that "open questions" surrounding the adaptive benefit of traits seem to be such a hot topic of research. My impression from skimming the Nature article you linked (but I will take a closer look) is that it is arguing that genetic drift *should* be treated as the null hypothesis, the subtext being that in practice it often *isn't.*

Comment: @Max "selectionist"/"adaptationist" arguments emphasizing the role of active selection in shaping observed diversity are often dominant, yes. It's more fun/publishable/suitable for textbooks to do work on surprising things than on boring things, even if boring things are more numerous. Hyperdarwinist views are emphasized by evo psych, "new atheism", etc.... To a degree you could call it an overreaction against creationism. For an old but well known criticism, see [here](https://embryo.asu.edu/pages/spandrels-san-marco-and-panglossian-paradigm-critique-adaptationist-programme-1979-stephen-j).

Comment: Is "hyperdarwinist" a synonym or antonym of "selectionist" here?

Comment: @Max neither - selectionist/neutralist differences are reasonably opposing views about how traits evolve. "hyperdarwinist" are those who unscientifically try and shoe-horn every observation about the natural world into some kind of story about selection.

Comment: @Max - you say you just want to learn, but your arguments don’t support your statement.

Comment: In order to gain a deeper understanding of the topic, I ask a lot of "why" questions. I am asking in good faith.